# Paypal Rest API - Immediate Payment life time

Tags: api, rest, paypal, sandbox

i didn't find any information about life time of payments with intent "sale". If a user cancel's payment by closing the paypal window, then i should be abled to continue payment by looking up the payment via api and redirect him to the approval url. But this works only for a certain time span. I'm abled to look up payments from yesterday, the response tells me about a payment state of "created" but after redirection to the approve_url paypal's website says:

***Your Session has ended.**
This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.*

I guess i should create a new payment in that case. But how long should i wait before creating a new payment, because payments with age.. - lets say about 1 hour are still valid?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user has three hours to approve of the PayPal payment before a new payment must be created.

Comment: It would be good if the API returns such information. Ideally, both the expiration time, when creating the payment and status="expired" when reading it back.