# PayPal immediate payment (intent="sale") expiration time

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm using the [Express Checkout flow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/) with the [advanced server integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/).

So I reserve items in real time once user has clicked the "Checkout" button and wait for the success\fail response. User can just close the browser tab and it will look like a long payment process (there is no way for the JS code to call the `onCancel` handler).

So it looks like I don't know if user has closed the browser or just fell asleep. Problem that I can't wait too long (more than ~5 mins) and I want to cancel the payment after this time. And it seems that I can't cancel the Payment myself. So user can come back and pay after N minutes (N > 5) for the item which has been un-reserved and is already out of stock.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592901/paypal-rest-api-immediate-payment-life-time) says:

> user has three hours to approve of the PayPal payment

1. Answer about 3 hours is a bit old so do we have any fresh DOCS about the immediate payment lifetime? **Is it still 3 hours for the REST Express Checkout flow?**
2. 3 hours is too long period for me. **Is there a way to setup the expiration time or timeout for the payment during creation?**
3. **Is there a way to cancel the Payment?** [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/) has no reference about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `GET` on the `PAY-XXXX` id.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get

The response comes with a `create_time` field. You should be able to check the delta from `create_time -> now`, and if it's > 5 minutes, don't accept the `PAY-XXXX` id / cancel the transaction in your database.

Does that work for your use case?

Also note: No money is moved until you call `execute`, so long as you prevent `execute` calls for old transactions, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is still 3 hours and there is no way to set it up during the payment creation. But i would assume that buyer cannot pay until he returns back to your site either by approving or without approving. So is it not possible to put a check in between the step where buyer comes back and then call to complete the payment is made?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I prefer to see some official documentation rather than guess. Please read the Express checkout flow with the advanced server integration one more time and ask your question once more then. Don't understand what checking are you talking about.